# Calling within Europe

Tags: europe, france, italy, switzerland, communication

I am traveling this spring in Switzerland, France and Italy.  I want to be able to make just a handful of local calls in each country.  I will NOT be using my American cellphone to call the United States when I'm there.  (Might not even bring it with me if I don't need it.)   What are the simplest and least costly methods of making local calls in these three countries-- with emphasis on France?   (At the same time, I don't want to rely on local "phone booths".)

Comment: Just buy a cheap phone and get a local SIM... Is there anything else you want to mention?

Comment: Do you need to make these calls from a cell phone or from your hotel room or some other place with WiFi? An account with some Voice-over-IP provider may be a suitable for you. For example, Skype comes into mind as the most well-known US-based provider (besides google, probably) and can be used on mobile devices (e.g., Android) over Wifi. Note that some US based phone companies charge ridiculous roaming fees once you turn on your phone abroad even when people speak to your mailbox, so you may consider switching the mailbox off or - as you mentioned - leaving your phone switched off completely.

Answer (score 4):

You should buy a SIM card in one or more of the countries.  You may find that the first one you buy can be used in other countries, or you may have to buy a new one in each country.  Be prepared to spend roughly 20-30 Euro for each SIM card.  And make sure you have a phone that actually takes SIM cards and is unlocked.  If you're coming from the US it may be easiest to buy a "dumb phone" ($35 or so online) for travelling.

If you want data service too, you may be best served by buying a cheap smartphone when you arrive, because the bands are different in different parts of the world, e.g. a US phone used in Europe will often have poor data speeds, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

The good news for you is that roaming charges within EU member states are [legally capped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations#Prices) at a very low level (19ct./min and 6ct./text), so a French SIM card will work quite well in Italy and vice versa. Furthermore, prepaid SIM cards are extremely cheap, as in 20€, including a simple phone and 5€ of credit.

Unfortunately, Switzerland does not belong to the EU, and the roaming rates in both directions (Swiss SIM in EU, and EU SIM in Switzerland) can be horrifying (such as 1.80 CHF / minute). If you plan to spend more than just a few minutes on the phone in Switzerland, I suggest getting another cheap SIM card there as well. [M-Budget Mobile](http://shop.m-budget.migros.ch/de/mobile-prepaid) has offers starting around 20 CHF, including 15 CHF of credit.

On the other hand, if using WiFi and VoIP is an option, Swiss federal train stations offer 1 hour of [free Wifi](http://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/am-bahnhof/dhl-service-point/free-wifi.html) per day (per station), though I haven't tried to use VoIP with that, so I can't comment on the connection speed.

Comment: my german prepaid sim has the same roaming rates for the eu and for switzerland, so the rates in the switzerland can be horrifying, as you said, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest, but not simplest option is to use public WiFi.

For cheap and simple, get a French or Italian SIM, one with low roaming rates to all of Europe.

---

**Details**

The EU roaming rates are pretty low, by law. Switzerland is not part of the EU, and the telecom cartel is quite strong there (the biggest provider for this 8 million people country is valued at 27 billion $ for a reason), so roaming there can be expensive depending on the provider.

For simplicity, many EU providers offer the same roaming rates for all of Europe, including Switzerland. That means the cheapest EU SIMs offer roaming rates in Switzerland that are lower than local rates of the more expensive Swiss SIMs.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about Switzerland. I was in Switzerland last year and I  bought a SIM card from swissCom. The call rates and data charges were pretty cheap. The SIM card costed me 20CHF and was credited with 30CHF (it's actually 20CHF  but due to some offer, I got 30 CHF credited to my account). For more information [here's a link to Swisscom](http://www.swisscom.ch/en/residential/mobile/subscription-tariffs/natel-easy-smart.html).

Comment: Swisscom is usually the most expensive option by far. There are various vendors specializing in calls abroad. Best go to a Mobilezone shop, which sells SIMs from a variety of providers, so they can assist in selecting one that is cheap and will be activated almost instantly.